# How to retain non-string objects across stages in a declarative Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In a declarative-pipeline Jenkinsfile, it seems that changes in the properties on the `env` variable are retained across stages and across restarts of the pipeline regardless of stage.  However, it seems that everything on `env` must be a string.  Is there any way to retain non-string content across stages--without using `env` or writing to a file?

Specifically, I was thinking I might use `params` for this, but it seems that values in `params` can't be changed.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To retain the value of a variable across stages, define a variable outside your pipeline with @Field annotation

```
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field def toto

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
       stage('stage1') {
           steps {
               toto = { name -> println name }  
           }
       }
       stage('stage2') {
           steps {
               println toto('toto')
           }
       }
    }
}
```

the variable will not survive restart.

To survive restart you could serialize and save your variable's value to a file and unserialize it at the first stage if the file is present